# Adding active content to the Atlas in composer $scale

Tags: print-composer, scale, text, atlas

I have an Atlas of 178 pages that centers on different size villages, its all well organised through the composer and all works well. However, I can't use the scale bar as the differences between village area is far too great, I thought it would be simple just to add some rich text a link to the `$scale` of the sheet in the atlas..

Any ideas...?